# Motion Tracking: When will "Prepass" enhance Motion Tracking quality?

Tags: tracking

I tried to figure out, when *Prepass* should be used in the Motion Tracking Settings. I understand from the [wiki](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/movie_clip/tracking/clip/editing/track.html) that...

> **Prepass**
>
> *Enables a two pass tracking, where the first pass is a brute force tracking of location only, and the second pass will use tracking of the full motion model refining the first pass.*

However, I don't yet know if enabling it if I want to track a marker in a video with fixed lighting and a fixed camera will improve my tracking quality.

Under which circumstances is Prepass advantageous and when should it not be used?